# How to set focus on a client under mouse cursor when a tag is changed?

Tags: awesome-wm

When I switch to another tag, a new client gets selected, but it is sometimes not a client that I have my mouse cursor over. To get a client under my mouse pointer focused, I have to either click somewhere on it, or switch to it with <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>j / k</kbd>, or move mouse cursor out and back on that client.

I want awesome to give focus to a client that is under the mouse cursor whenever a tag is changed. How do I do that?

I found a function [mouse.object_under_pointer()](https://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/mouse.html#object_under_pointer) that finds the client I need, but I don't know when to call that function. Should I connect a handler to some particular signal? I tried connecting to various signals from [Signals page on the wiki](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Signals) and checking with `naughty.notify()` if that is the right signal, but none of them were triggered when I was switching between tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code did the trick, however there should be a better way to do this than setting up a huge 200 ms timer (smaller timeouts didn't properly focus some clients for me, but you can try setting a smaller one).

```lua
tag.connect_signal(
  "property::selected",
  function (t)
    local selected = tostring(t.selected) == "false"
    if selected then
      local focus_timer = timer({ timeout = 0.2 })
      focus_timer:connect_signal("timeout", function()
        local c = awful.mouse.client_under_pointer()
        if not (c == nil) then
          client.focus = c
          c:raise()
        end
        focus_timer:stop()
      end)
      focus_timer:start()
    end
  end
)
```

`tag` is [this global object](https://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/tag.html), so you should just place this code anywhere in your `rc.lua`.

Comment: Wow. I had been trying to accomplish this, but mine didn't work until I added the delay. Mine works if you use a timeout as small as 1ms.

Comment: Instead of `property::selected`, I used `tag::history::update` on a client object. This means that it will run whenever there is a change to tags (such as toggling tags, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is pretty old, but it helped me to come up with this

```
function focus_client_under_mouse()
    gears.timer( {  timeout = 0.1,
                    autostart = true,
                    single_shot = true,
                    callback =  function()
                                    local n = mouse.object_under_pointer()
                                    if n ~= nil and n ~= client.focus then
                                        client.focus = n end
                                    end
                  } )
end

screen.connect_signal( "tag::history::update", focus_client_under_mouse )
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things should be done:

First, you should remove `require("awful.autofocus")` from your config, so that this module no longer tries to focus some client via the focus history when you switch tags.

Then, this code works for me:

```
do
    local pending = false
    local glib = require("lgi").GLib
    tag.connect_signal("property::selected", function()
        if not pending then
            pending = true
            glib.idle_add(glib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE, function()
                pending = false
                local c = mouse.current_client
                if c then
                    client.focus = c
                end
                return false
            end)
        end
    end)
end
```

This uses GLib directly to get a callback for when no other events are pending. This should mean that "everything else" was handled.